# Eclipse - simulate full disk when running server

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I have a small application which doesn't take up lots of space (the application does a lot of disk writing, so data accumulates) and I need to know what happens when the disk is full and the application is still trying to write to the disk; whether parts fail or the entire thing.

I'm currently running Tomcat within Eclipse and I would like to know if there is a way to limit the disk space allowed to a server created in Eclipse. Any Ideas?

Comment: Create a device with minimal space. Use this device as your target. BTW: What is your OS?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, is there a guide as to how to do that somewhere? I'm not sure what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a small RAM drive, which can be used like a physical drive but exists entirely in RAM. This has the added benefit that is really fast and that you don't have to delete your test files afterwards, as the contents will be gone after your RAM drive is closed.

As for how exactly you create your RAM drive, this depends on your operating system.
In Linux, you can use `tmpfs` (taken from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66329/creating-a-ram-disk-on-linux):

`mount -o size=16G -t tmpfs none /mnt/tmpfs`

Edit: In Windows, this isn't shipped with your system so you need to install additional software. A list of it can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software.

Comment: "I'm using Windows 7". Sad, but true.

Comment: good answer, I found this for windows: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/create-10-gbs-ram-disk-windows/

Comment: @LutzHorn, you can't always choose your dev environment.